# Create dynamic object C#

Tags: object, dynamic

How can I do this?

```
 List<string> lltest = new List<string>{ "Id", "Nome","Valor" };
 List<object> obj2 = new List<object>();
 foreach (string l in lltest)
 {
   var a = new { l = "asd"  };
   obj2.Add(a);
 }
```

l will always be l. All I want is to create an object where the name is from the string list. I need the name of the object to be dynamic, ex:Id = asd, Nome = "asd", and so on..

To explain the scenario I have a datatable that renders the columns based on the properties, when I fetch the DeclaredProperties it need to be in the format of an object. If I use dynamic the properties will be different.

I can't believe this can't be done!

### Update

Found my solution on [this amazing link](https://jonathancrozier.com/blog/time-to-reflect-how-to-add-properties-to-a-c-sharp-object-dynamically-at-runtime).

Comment: Maybe if u specify the language you're using to code, we can help you better :D

Try also to explain what you want to do with this piece of code.

Comment: sry.. its c#.. i will edit